# Bootstrap vertically shifts <strong> text within a <td> for some reason -- how to fix this?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, twitter-bootstrap

Using the latest straight download of Twitter Bootstrap, the following

```
<table class="table">
    <tr><td>not bold <strong>bold</strong> not bold</td></tr>
</table>
```

causes the bold text (i.e. the word "bold") to be slightly shifted downward so that it's no longer vertical on the same line as the rest of the text.

I see the downward shift with Chrome and Safari but NOT with Firefox. (EDIT: based on the comments, it seems this may only happen on a Mac.)

Is this supposed to happen? Am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug, any suggested workaround?

Comment: just tried this (http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/Tkv3C/) in Chrome and Safari (on Windows), I see no vertical shifting. Can you provide a demo of the problem? Perhaps you have other CSS that is causing the issue?

Comment: @jackwanders I see his problem

Comment: @Wex odd. Can you post a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: Most likely, this is only happening on Mac.

Comment: @thirtydot - yep I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/uC5ax/

Change `vertical-align: top` in `.table td`

```
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

to `vertical-align: text-bottom`

```
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, to keep the table formatting is to simply delete the problematic rows from:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;
  > thead,
  > tbody,
  > tfoot {
    > tr {
      > th,
      > td {
        padding: @table-cell-padding;
        line-height: @line-height-base;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 1px solid @table-border-color;
      }
    }
  }
  > thead > tr > th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: 2px solid @table-border-color;
  }
  > caption + thead,
  > colgroup + thead,
  > thead:first-child {
    > tr:first-child {
      > th,
      > td {
        border-top: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  > tbody + tbody {
    border-top: 2px solid @table-border-color;
  }

  .table {
    background-color: @body-bg;
  }
}
```

to

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;
  > thead,
  > tbody,
  > tfoot {
    > tr {
      > th,
      > td {
        padding: @table-cell-padding;
        line-height: @line-height-base;
        border-top: 1px solid @table-border-color;
      }
    }
  }
  > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid @table-border-color;
  }
  > caption + thead,
  > colgroup + thead,
  > thead:first-child {
    > tr:first-child {
      > th,
      > td {
        border-top: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  > tbody + tbody {
    border-top: 2px solid @table-border-color;
  }

  .table {
    background-color: @body-bg;
  }
}
```